# Merge CSV files with different header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple CSV files which all have a datetime feature and are sorted according to datetime. Some csv files might have some missing dates.

How can I combine all the CSV files with a common datetime column?

Examples of the headers of the files

**File 1:**

```
Date,Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4
```

**File 2:**

```
Date,Value
```

**File 3:**

```
DateTime,WP,WP1,WP2,WP3
```

Comment: Load each csv file into its own dataframe, they `join` or `merge` those dataframes on the common colum with `how='outer'`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Serge Ballesta mentioned:

```
df1=read_csv(file1)
df2=read_csv(file2)
df3=read_csv(file3)

df3['Date'] = df['DateTime'].dt.date
pd.merge(pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Date', how='outer'),df3, on='Date', how='outer')
```